# C# wrapper of facebook Grpah API

Tags: .net, facebook-graph-api

is there any library which I can use in .net application

actually What I want, is for the application to be able to use a person's facebook Login credentials as his Login credentials in my own membership tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one on codeplex [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)